# MVC Error "is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

I have a model like this;

```
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string MidName{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
```

This is my controller:

```
  public ActionResult Create(){
       ViewBag.Names= new SelectList(db.TbName, "ID", "MidName");
       return Viwe();
    }
```

This is my view

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Names, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Names", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Names)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now when click create button i get an error saying

> `The ViewData item that has the key 'Names' is of type 'System.Int32'
>   but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

I am getting this error is it because ID is int, if yes then how do i convert it?

Comment: Where is your action that receives the postback?

Comment: I've tried that suggestion but it doesn't work for me!

Comment: @MikeC. i think i dont have it. can you give a example?

Comment: Ehsan has an example below, although yours will need to have parameters as well. There's plenty of tutorials on how to do that so I won't bother posting another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to avoid dynamic stuff like ViewBag /ViewData as much as possible to transfer data between action methods and views. Let's build a strongly typed Viewmodel.

```
public class CreateCustomerVM
{
   public string MidName{ get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
   public string Surname{ get; set; }
   public List<SelectListItem> MidNames { set;get;}
   public CreateCustomerVM()
   {
     MidNames=new List<SelectListItem>();
   }
}
```

and in your `Create` action method

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new CreateCustomerVM();
  vm.MidNames=GetMidNames();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetMidNames()
{
  return new List<SelectListItem> { 
    new SelectListItem { Value="Mr", Text="Mr"},
    new SelectListItem { Value="Ms", Text="Ms"},
  };
}
```

and in your view, which is strongly typed to our viewmodel

```
@model CreateCustomerVM
@using(Html.Beginform())
{

 <div>
   Mid name : @Html.DropdownListFor(s=>s.MidName,Model.MidNames)
   FirstName : @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.FirstName)
   <input type="submit" />
 </div>

}
```

Now when your form is posted, You will get the selected item value in the `MidName` property of the viewmodel.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateCustomerVM customer)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //read customer.FirstName , customer.MidName 
    // Map it to the properties of your DB entity object
    // and save it to DB
  }
  //Let's reload the MidNames collection again.
  customer.MidNames=GetMidNames();
  return View(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, ViewBag.Names, new Dictionary<string, object>{{"class", "control-label col-md-2"}})
```

That should work.

Comment: I get an error: `'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Essence.Essence_RunningRecords>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.` You was missing ) so this is what i've used `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, ViewBag.Names, new Dictionary <string, object>{{"class", "control-label col-md-2"}})`

Answer (score 0):

populate in viewbag again in post action of create:

```
public ActionResult Create(){
       ViewBag.Names= new SelectList(db.TbName, "ID", "MidName");
       return View();
    }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(){
       ViewBag.Names= new SelectList(db.TbName, "ID", "MidName");
       return View();
    }
```

or try with helper like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Names,
           new Dictionary<string, object>{{"class", "control-label col-md-2"}})
```

Comment: I do have a httpPost in my code, and it looks exactly like this.

Comment: can you provide definition of TbName??

Comment: Thats in my model.Context.cs file it goes something like this: `        public virtual DbSet<Name> TbName{ get; set; }
`

Comment: what is inisde it can you tell the properties in edit of post